# ionic 2 open google maps with directions from 2 locations

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, directions

I need to open google maps when i click a button and show directions from a source location and destination location. By searching a lot i figured out a way with InAppBrowser, but it doesnt work.

Here is the code i found:

```
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((data) => {
      let lat = data.coords.latitude;
      let lng = data.coords.longitude;
      let bro = new InAppBrowser;

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        bro.create('geo://?q=&saddr=' + data.coords.latitude + ',' + data.coords.longitude + '&daddr=' + this.dataitem['lat'] + ',' + this.dataitem['lng'], '_system');
      };
      if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        bro.create('geo://?q=' + data.coords.latitude + ',' + data.coords.longitude + '&daddr=' + this.dataitem['lat'] + ',' + this.dataitem['lng'] + '', '_system');
      };
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  });
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried using [IonicNative](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator/) for this task?  This might be preferable than trying to do it with a query string to the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Install **[Launch Navigator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator/)** plugins:

1. Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

> ionic cordova plugin add
> uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/launch-navigator

2. add LaunchNavigator into **app.module.ts**
3. Add this code into your ts file :

   ```
   source: any = [22.303894, 70.802160] // source lat,long
   destination: any =  [23.022505, 72.571362] // dest lat,long

   navigate(){

   let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
      start: this.source
   };

    this.launchnavigator.navigate(this.destination, options)
      .then(
       success => alert('Launched navigator'),
       error => alert('Error launching navigator: ' + error)
    );
   }
   ```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to open maps, make sure In App Browser plugin is installed.

```
let destination = latitude + ',' + longitude;

if(this.platform.is('ios')){
  window.open('maps://?q=' + destination, '_system');
} else {
 let label = encodeURI('My Label');
 window.open('geo:0,0?q=' + destination + '(' + label + ')', '_system');
}
```

[Reference](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/open-navigation-app-to-navigate-to-adress/47178)